# Why does my program stop working if I add a variable?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

Why is it that if I remove `var framesPerSecond`, the program runs fine? Even if I put the variable inside `window.onload` it doesn't work.

```
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas;
var canvasContext;
var ballX = 50;
var ballSpeedX = 5;
var framesPerSecond = math.random()*(100-10)+10;
window.onload = function() {
canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
setInterval(callBoth, framesPerSecond);
}

function callBoth() {
  moveEverything();
  drawEverything();
}

function moveEverything() {
  ballX = ballX + ballSpeedX;
  if(ballX > canvas.width) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
  if(ballX < 0) {
    ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
  }
}

function drawEverything() {
// canvas
  colorRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height,'black');
// obstacles
  colorRect(40,40,720,520,'blue');
// car
  colorRect(ballX,100,10,10,'white');
}

function colorRect(leftX, topY, width, height, drawColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = drawColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(leftX, topY, width, height);
}
</script>
```

Ps. I am just a beginner.

Comment: The console should tell you the problem.

Comment: There was obviously no debugging attempt for this. "it doesn't work" isn't a descriptive issue.

Comment: I have never debugged anything before, I have no idea of how to go about it.

Comment: And a tipp for your `setInterval()` call. The second parameter tells the browser the **delay between two executions** of the function passed as the first parameter.

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Okay. Understood.

Comment: The question "how can I debug my javascript" has some outdated answers. Just press F12 and the developer tools of your browser should open. My favorite is [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and used to hate having to debug something in IE but Edge got better (still prefer Chrome though). The developer tools console tab should have shown you the error.

Comment: I would also advice you to get vs code or atom as your ES editor, they will auto suggest some things that will prevent you from mis typing certain properties.

Comment: I am already using atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math` should be capitalized:
`var framesPerSecond = Math.random()*(100-10)+10;`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.